# Compute the Möbius function values µ(i, j) for each ordered pair (i, j) in {0, 1, . . . , k + 1}.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Consider the partial order $\preceq$ on $\{0, 1, 2,\ldots,k +1\}$ for which the resulting poset
P has the Hasse diagram as shown.

[image]

Compute the Möbius function values $\mu(i, j)$ for each ordered pair $(i, j)$ in
$\{0, 1, \ldots, k + 1\}$.

My solution:
$$\mu(0,k + 1) = - \sum_{z \in [0, k+1)} \mu(0, z) = -1 + 1 +  \ \ ... \ \ 1, (+ 1\ \ k \ \ times) = k - 1$$

since, $\mu(0,0) = -1$ else $\mu(0, z) = 1$ as they are chains of length 2.

Am I right in my calculation? This is my first time using the Mobius function.

Answer (score 1):

No, you’ve got the sign wrong. $\mu(x,x)=1$ for all $x\in P$, so $\mu(0,0)=1$. And the chains from $0$ to $z$ for $z=1,\ldots,k$ are of length $1$, not $2$; the length of a chain is the number of edges in the chain, not the number of vertices. Thus $\mu(0,z)=-1$ for $z=1,\ldots,k$. Your result for $\mu(0,k+1)$ is nevertheless correct, but only because you made another sign error that cancels the other one. From your values for $\mu(0,0)$ and $\mu(0,z)$ for $z=1,\ldots,k$, you should have obtained $-(k-1)$, but since those are off by a sign, the correct result is indeed $\mu(0,k+1)=k-1$.